# PHP MYSQL $_GET['ID'] from table on dynamically generated page

Tags: php, mysql, database, get

I have a few products stored in a table with auto-incremented ID entitled "product_id".

I have managed to create a page that displays a list of the products names as selected from the db and dynamically created links for each one. Let's say I have product apple. When I click on apple it takes me to view_product_details.php?id=9

But when I click apple, the view_product_details.php page tells me
"Notice: Undefined index: product_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\working\product-website-exercise\view_product_details.php on line 16"

```
<?php 

//$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM temaproduct.products WHERE ID = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['product_id'])."'");


        $id = $_GET['product_id']; //This is line 16

        $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM products WHERE ID = $id");

        echo $result['product_description'];

echo "<br>";
var_dump($result);

?>
```

I have tried with different queries but can't figure it out, please help me establish the connection properly so I can read the other fields from the table on the view_product_details page, based on product_id.

EDIT: Thank you guys, with your help, here is the code that works now, if everybody needs this snippet:

```
<?php
$id = intval($_GET['id']); 
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = ".$id);
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)){
    $product_data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
    echo "<h2><center>".$product_data['title']."</h2></center>";
}
?>
```

Comment: show how did you pass `product_id`?

Comment: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Use `$_GET['id']` instead of `$_GET['product_id']`

Comment: and secondly use mysql_fetch_* for fetching rows from database :) @ThomasRollet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using id as a query string in this URL as:

```
view_product_details.php?id=9
```

So, you need to get id as:

```
$id = $_GET['id']; //This is line 16
```

Second issue in your code is that, you can not get result from database without using `mysqli_fetch_*` function.

```
echo $result['product_description']; // this will return nothing
```

---

**Your Modified Code:**

```
<?
$id = intval($_GET['id']); 
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM products WHERE ID = ".$id);
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)){
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
    echo $result['product_description'];
}
else{
    echo "No record found";
}
?>
```

---

**Suggestion:**

You need to do one more thing, please use `intval()` function if any one pass string or anything else in the query string than your query will not return an error only return 0 record like:

**Example:**

```
view_product_details.php?id=abcdJUNK
```

**Than convert it into 0 as:**

```
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
```

---

**For Future Visitors:**

After debugging, found this error "**Unknown Column ID**"

so correct query was this as OP mentioned (**column name was product_id**):

```
SELECT * FROM hangouts WHERE product_id = 9
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, but var_dump($result); still says bool(false) instead of showing me the product description.

Comment: @J.Doe: check your connection $result will return a resource id if your connection is working fine..

Comment: I replaced mine with your modified code, I now get two errors:
1. mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\working\product-website-exercise\view_product_details.php on line 18

2. Notice: Undefined variable: result in C:\xampp\htdocs\working\product-website-exercise\view_product_details.php on line 24

Comment: did u checked $conn connection in your code?? what r u getting in var_dump($sql);   this should return a resource id, if not than check your connection. @J.Doe

Comment: var_dump($sql) outputs bool(false). I don't know how to check connection but it should work considering I copied and pasted it from my other file where I've retrieved the list of products from the db successfully. I don't know where I'm going with programming, is really tough learning on my own and feels like I've wasted the last three months of my life.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101894/discussion-between-devpro-and-j-doe).

Comment: dont feel like that, atleast u r trying to kill animals. join the chat @J.Doe

Comment: Ok, so apparently, "SELECT * FROM hangouts WHERE ID = 9" was incorrect, it should have been "SELECT * FROM hangouts WHERE product_id = 9" if anybody is curious.

Answer (score 1):

According to your code and URL that you provide you are passing value in variable `id` not in `product_id`. This is your URL `view_product_details.php?id=9` here value is in variable `id` i.e `id=9`.

```
$id = $_GET['id']; //This is line 16
```

Answer (score 1):

You are actually passing `id` in `view_product_details.php?id=9` query params not `product_id` in the url.

To use `product_id` you can change the url like `view_product_details.php?product_id=9` or you can use `$_GET['id']`

& replace  this line

```
$id = $_GET['product_id'];
```

with this

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

> You can use `get_defined_vars`(http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php) to check which variables are
>   available.

Also I suggest you suppress your errors for production & show all errors in developement.

> **To hide errors in production**

```
ini_set("display_errors", 0);
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
```

> **To show errors in developement**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

two problems here first your name attribute in html form is different then what you are using in php i changed the php code for that issue and second problem is you are missing to convert the result in to assosiative array and directly calling the product description just read the comments in modified version of code down below.

this is your current code

```
    $id = $_GET['product_id']; //This is line 16

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM products WHERE ID = $id");

    echo $result['product_description'];
```

this is how it should be

```
    // this is the solution for first issue
    $id = $_GET['id']; //This is line 16

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM products WHERE ID = $id");

    // this is the solution for second issue
    // covert it to associative array
    $resultData = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    echo $resultData['product_description'];
```

Comment: replace $_GET['product_id'] into $_GET['id'] :)

Comment: everyone was new and confused in early days my brother happy coding.. :)